# Embarrassed for vs embarrassed about

Tags: prepositions

> All students should be wearing the same uniforms, so they don't have to feel embarrassed **for** their clothes.

Should it be "for" or "about"?

Comment: The 'for' form is usually used about someone else: 'I'm embarrassed for Simon; he made such an idiot of himself'.

Comment: The sentence is not idiomatic in my experience and would be immediately recognised as “strange” to most native English speakers in Australia, despite being easily understood. Where did you see this sentence?

Comment: @OrbitalAussie It is no less strange to a Pommie, mate. Sounds like the writer has great concerns about the clothes' personal feelings!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be embarrassed for **someone**.  I would be embarrassed in their situation, whether or not they are.

I may be embarrassed about **something**.

The degree of embarrassment would depend on my ability to control or to have controlled the situation in the past.